# Issue with Haneke component for Xamarin, possibly linker issue

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-linker

Haneke component for Xamarin seems to be quite solid, nevertheless I'm having strange issue with it on devices though **on sim all works as expected**. The app compiles and builds ok. But when launched on device when `imageView.SetImage(imageUrl);` then this happens:

> -[UIImageView hnk_setImageFromURL:placeholder:success:failure:] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x181b8090

Seems like extension method can't be discovered and the corresponding header **.h** file is missing or something like that in Haneke.dll itself. Code for the method call is:

```
                HanekeUIImageView.SetImage(photoCell.ImageView,//explicit call to extension method
                //this is something that I 
                //tried, the 'usual way' of method call
                //photoCell.ImageView.SetImage(
                    new NSUrl(link),
                    EmptyImage,
                    SuccessAction ?? new Action<UIImage>((img) => {
                        SLogger.Write("Image loaded for picture url {0}\n", link);
                        photoCell.ImageView.Image = img;
                    }),
                    FailureAction ?? new Action<NSError>((err) => {
                        SLogger.Write("Image load failed for picture url {0} with error {1}\n", link, err);
                    })
                );
```

Also, I would like to note that I've tried umm:) I guess all possible combinations of linker options and of course "Don't link", "Link SDK assemblies only", "Link all" in VS studio Build project tab.

Comment: If it does not work with **Don't link** then it's not a *managed* linker issue, still you might want to try setting different linker settings on the simulator to be 100% sure. The next step would be for you to ensure that this symbols is part of the `arm*` slice of your native library (.a).

Comment: It's not  native library .a file - it's Haneke.dll, not sure how can I check that it has arm* slice, and yes  - on sim all linker settings do work. Thanks

Comment: Binding components embeds the native library (.a) inside the .dll so it's easier to consume from applications.

Comment: Did you find an answer on this? Having same issue

Comment: Umm, well - yes and no, no cause not with Haneke:( but solved it with SDWebImage. It had glitch in table view due to cell refresh - but I fixed it with setting of image width in override in delegate.

Comment: Strange there is such an issue with Haneke - a published component in Xamarin component store, so it must be something specific to particular system/project setup.